# fish shell: sudo password needed for docker command with each session

Tags: bash, docker, permissions, sudo, fish

With each new session in a fish shell a have to re-enter my sudo password. I run ubuntu 20.04 and have followed these [instruction steps for docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

In my bash shell I am able to execute docker commands without sudo password. Whenever I switch to my fish shell I **do** have to enter my password. It will be valid for the session with whatever default timeout is set in `/etc/sudoers`.

In both shells I can see that I belong to the same groups

```
$ groups <me>
... <me> sudo ... docker
```

I don't really understand the underlying reason and therefore also don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a function or alias for docker in bash? What is the output of `type -a docker`?

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed: I have a bunch of fish functions that I ported from my old installation to my brand new 20.04. `ln -s /github/fish_functions ~/.config/fish/functions`, they actually contain a function `docker` that calls `sudo docker`. Apparently something that was needed in my old 16.04 install? Thanks @glennjackman!